# JFormattedTextField returns default value only

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jformattedtextfield

I put a JFormattedTextField (instantiated with a NumberFormatter and given an initial random value) in a panel and that panel goes in a JOptionPane which gets displayed. When then I type a different random value in that JFormattedTextField and click OK, the JFormattedTextField returns the original value, not the one just typed in?! Minimal code example below. Hope you can help.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;
import java.awt.*;

public class Weg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final NumberFormatter numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
        numberFormatter.setMinimum(0);
        numberFormatter.setMaximum(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        panel.add(new JLabel("Enter positive value:"));
        JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormatter);
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 1));
        textField.setValue(999.1); //Random initial value
        panel.add(textField);

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 35));
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Enter a value", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            double val = (double) textField.getValue();
            System.out.println("Value entered = " + val); //Whatever you enter, the old 999.1 is returned here???
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that tutorial. It doesn't help me in solving my issue though. I even tried adding textField.commitEdit(); (within a try/catch), but this does not help either. So I am still stuck...

Comment: I used the tutorial as a reference to compare how you create the formatted text field and how the tutorial created the formatted text field. I used the tutorial approach and it worked fine.

Comment: Great. Can you share your code? Thanks...

Comment: I did share the code. I said the code in the tutorial works fine. Learn by example. Its two lines of code to use a formatted text field. You create the NumberFormat and use that to create the JFormattedTextField.

Comment: I have spent 8 hrs trying to solve this, to no avail. The tutorial uses a NumberFormat obj (used in the JFormattedTextField creation) with which you can play with number of decimal places etc. However, you cannot set the range. That's why I used a NumberFormatter object instead, on which you *can* set min/max, but ... it doesn't work as we know. If you have the time and inclination to help me out, I appreciate it. If not, we just have to leave it as is, which is a bit unfortunate, as the code clearly is not what I want it to be. Thanks - Michael

Comment: *The tutorial uses a NumberForma* - so you proved a formatted text field works when properly configured. *I used a NumberFormatter object instead, on which you can set min/max,* - so problem solve one step at a time. What happens when you use a NumberFormatter but don't set the min/max? What happens when you just set the min? What happens when you just set the max? What is the different between the min/max parameters?

Comment: If in the instantiation of the JFormattedTextfield I use a NumberFormatter object for which neither min nor max max have been set or for which only min or max have been set, then (double)textField.getValue() returns a class cast exception, as a long cannot be cast to a double. If the NumberFormatter object has min *and* max set, we get the error I described at the start. Does this help in any way? I still don't see it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the code you posted with your question.

When tested as is I see the problem you describe. That is I:

1. deleted the first 9
2. tab
3. click Ok

The result:

1. 999.1 is still displayed in the formatted text field
2. `Value entered = 999.1` is displayed on the console.

I then make the following change:

```
//numberFormatter.setMinimum(0);
//numberFormatter.setMaximum(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

and repeat the 3 steps above with the following result:

1. 99.1 is displayed in the formatted text field
2. `Value entered = 99.1` is displayed on the console.

So it works as expected.

Next I try:

```
numberFormatter.setMinimum(0);
//numberFormatter.setMaximum(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

and repeat the 3 steps with the result:

1. 99 is displayed in the formatted text field
2. get Exception: `class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double`

So I realize the minimum value is being created as an Integer, not a Double so I try:

```
numberFormatter.setMinimum( Double.valueOf(0) );
//numberFormatter.setMaximum(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

with the result:

1. 99.1 is displayed in the formatted text field
2. `Value entered = 99.1` is displayed on the console.

So it works as expected.

Finally I try:

```
numberFormatter.setMinimum( Double.valueOf(10) );
//numberFormatter.setMaximum(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
```

and delete the first two digits so only "9.1" is displayed, with the result:

1. 999.1 is displayed in the formatted text field
2. `Value entered = 999.1` is displayed on the console.

The the minimum value was respected and the code works as expected.

I don't know why you would try to set the max value, since that is obviously the default.

This is how you do basic debugging one step at a time. The point is to first isolate the problem by making a single change at a time.

Comment: +1Thanks - things now work much better but ... still not quite as I wished, as the user can enter a negative value and click OK. The user may then think a negative value is used in the ensuing logic. whereas under the hood the default value in the textfield is used...